# CentOS 7: Python2.7.5 got overwritten and can't use yum or python2

Tags: centos, python, yum, rpm, torque

I was installing the Torque queue system onto my CentOS 7 server, and after running the config command for the installation, my default python2 version (2.7.5) got overwritten and replaced by python2.7.18. Python2.7.18 was installed onto my server but with the intent of turning it into a virtual environment so I can integrate it with the environment module system. This had not been done yet, but Python2.7.18 was never added to the path nor was any command involving python ever involved. After looking through my bash history, I noticed that my last working yum command was right before running the config command for Torque and after that point, it stopped working.

I attempted to reinstall 2.7.5 through RPM but even after installing all the necessary dependencies and the python2 RPM, I am presented with this error:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>

Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>

Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]

ImportError: No module named site
```

I'm at my wits end with this and can not figure out how to get python2 to start working again, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried booting into a CentOS 7 live USB and copying the Python 2.7.5 data into the installation?

Comment: I don't have access to the physical machine right now, I'm utilizing an SSH connection as I'm running two servers for a lab. Could I potentially take a similar route and copy over the working version of python2.7.5 from the one server and send it to the server that is broken? The file structure is identical on both servers.

Comment: So CentOS actually uses a different binary for python2.7.5 and python2.7.18, or is it the library directories? I'm used to seeing `/usr/lib/python2.7` and `/usr/lib/python3.10`; these *should* include all minor versions (python2.7.x or python 3.10.x).

Comment: What does /usr/bin/python point at?

Comment: Before you do any of that, is it that Python 2.7.5 was replaced or that it's actually still there while Python 2.7.18 is just what is in your environment? Add the output of `whereis python`. It's for this reason that it's best to create a virtual environment as regular user and not in a root shell.

Comment: Python2.7.5 was completely replaced. The executables in /usr/bin got overwritten and are now linked with 2.7.18 and not 2.7.5. The /usr/lib/python2.7 directories however are still linked to Python2.7.5 even though there is no existing binary for it. I do now have a working version of python on the server again (2.7.8) but the issue now is getting yum to link with it.